# ¿Como autoincrementar una variable 1 en 1, segun registro creado dinamicamente, jquery?

Tags: jquery

actualmente genero una lista de productos dinamicamente
de esta forma:

```
var listado_ofertas_adicionales = $('.listado_ofertas_adicionales');
                       valCarrito = response.data;
                       $.each(valCarrito, function (i) {
                            $('<li/>').addClass('swipeout')
                                .append($('<div/>').addClass('swipeout-content item-content')
                                    .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-media')
                                        .append('<img src="' + valCarrito[i].Url + '" onerror="this.onerror=null;" alt="" width="40" height="60" />'))
                                    .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-inner')
                                        .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-title-row')
                                            .append($('<div style="font-size: 12px;"/>').addClass('item-title').append(valCarrito[i].Codigo_Inventario + " - " + valCarrito[i].Descripcion))
                                            .append('<div class="codInventario" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].Codigo_Inventario + '</div>')
                                            .append('<div class="tipo" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].Tipo + '</div>')
                                            .append('<div class="tipo_costo" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].TipoCosto + '</div>')
                                            .append('<div class="precioSocio" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].PrecioSocio + '</div>')
                                            .append('<div class="volumenNegocio" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].VolumenNegocio + '</div>')
                                            .append('<div class="item-after" data-unit-price="' + valCarrito[i].PrecioSocio + '"><span class="product-amount" style="font-size: 12px;">' + valCarrito[i].PrecioSocio + '</span></div>')
                                        )
                                        .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-text')
                                            /*.append('<input type="number" class="add_ofertas_adicionales" value="' + valCarrito[i].Cantidad + '" min="0" placeholder="Ingrese cantidad">')*/                                              
                                                .append($('<div/>').addClass('chip chip-small').append('<div class="chip-label"><span class="product-quantity">' + valCarrito[i].Cantidad + '</span></div>'))
                                                .append($('<div style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"/>').addClass('chip chip-small').append('<div class="chip-label"><button class="sumarOferta">+</button></div>'))
                                                .append($('<div style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"/>').addClass('chip chip-small').append('<div class="chip-label"><button class="restarOferta">-</button></div>'))
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
```

De este contenido dinámico debo ir aumentando la cantidad de productos a seleccionar.
Lo cual lo realizo de esta forma:

```
$('.listado_ofertas_adicionales').on('click','.sumarOferta',function(e){
        myApp.showIndicator();
        var el                  = $(this).closest('.swipeout');
            el_product_quantity = el.find('.product-quantity');
        var tipo                = el.find('.tipo').text();
        var codigoinventario    = el.find('.codInventario').text();
        var cantidad            = acrescimo;
        var tipocosto           = el.find('.tipo_costo').text();
        var preciosocio         = el.find('.precioSocio').text();
        var volumennegocio      = el.find('.volumenNegocio').text();
        addProductoOferta(idPedido,tipo,codigoinventario,cantidad,tipocosto,preciosocio,volumennegocio);
        //acrescimo = 0;
        console.log(cantidad)
        cantidad = acrescimo++;
        el_product_quantity.text(cantidad);

    });
```

El resultado queda de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El detalle es de que por cada cada vez que yo presione el boton mas **+** se debe ir aumentando de 1 en 1 el valor la clase `product-quantity` tal y como van se ve en el producto 1, el detalle es que si por ejemplo en el primer producto ya llevo una cantidad de 4, al momento de aumentar el valor por ejemplo en el producto 3 que esta en 0, obviamente le asigna el valor 5 que es el que correctamente le correspondería. 
**Entonces como podría llevar por cada registro su propio contador para ir sumando e ir restando.**, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es que uses un vector de enteros, y cada uno de los items corresponde a una posición y ahí guardas el contador. Lo otro es que veo que accedes a los elementos por la clase, es recomendable usar los id's. Ejemplo:
.append('' + valCarrito[i].Codigo_Inventario + '')

Y al final del apend haces algo como vecContadores.push(0);

Cuando quieras acceder al ítem usas el id ejemplo "#codInventario5" y sabes que su contador estará en vecContadores[5]

Saludos,

Comment: Buena noche compañero, por favor podrías darme tu solución aplicado a mi codigo, de antemano muy agradecido por tu tiempo.